# R-Randomly pick a number and do it over and over until a condition is achivied

Tags: r

I want to randomly pick a number from a vector with 8 elements that sums to 35. If the number is 0 look for another number. If the number is greater than 0, make this number -1. Do this in a loop until the sum of the vector is 20. How can I do this in R?
For example: `vec<-c(2,3,6,0,8,5,6,5)`

Pick a number from this list randomly and make the number -1 until the sum of the elements becomes 20.

Comment: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tutorial-on-loops-in-r#gs.KtblU9M - read this.

Comment: Why would this process converge to a sum of 20? One can obviously end up with anything less or equal to 20, but I would consider it pure luck to obtain a sum of *exactly* 20 after such manipulations.

Comment: to achieve the sum of the vector 20 is the condition, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really really not sure that is what you want, but for what I understand of your question, here is my solution.  You'll get most of the concept and key fonctions in my script.  Use that and help() to understand them and optimize it.

```
vec <- c(2, 3, 6, 0, 8, 5, 6, 5)

summ <- 0
new.vec <- NULL
iter <- 1
while(summ<20) {
 selected <- sample(vec,1)
 if(selected!=0) new.vec[iter] <- selected-1
 summ <- sum(new.vec)
 iter <- iter+1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
vec <- c(2, 3, 6, 0, 8, 5, 6, 5)
#just setting the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(19)
tabulate(sample(rep(seq_along(vec),vec),20))
#[1] 0 2 4 0 4 5 3 2
```

Comment: With the function set.seed will do 19 times randomly?!

Comment: We are just setting the seed for the random number generator. See `?set.seed`.